# A combinatorial proof of a binomial coefficient summation identity.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

$$\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m}{k}\binom{n+k}{m}=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{k}2^k$$
This is the exercise 3.3.6 of the book *Invitation to Discrete Mathematics*.

The answer in book is

> Let *M* be an *m*-element set and *N* be an *n*-element set. Both sides count the number of ordered pairs $$(X,Y)$$ with $$X\subseteq M, Y\subseteq N\cup X,\ and\ |Y|=m$$
> For the right-hand side, we first pick $$Y\cap N,$$ then $$Y\cap M$$ and finally X.

I'm confusing in the "finally X".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of summation i.e., $k'=m-k$ to $$\sum _{k=1}^{m}\binom{n}{m-k}\binom{m}{k}2^{m-k},$$
so $|Y\cap N|=m-k$ and  $|Y\cap M|=k$, then notice that you have $m-k$ left from $M$ just choose some set, say $Z$, where doesn't matter the length but is  such that $X=Y\cup Z$. The only requirement is that $Z\subseteq M\setminus Y$ and there are $2^{|M\setminus Y|}=2^{m-k}$ options.

Comment: Thanks for your ans

Comment: @ChoonLeeYan You are welcome